# Makefile include list of object files recursively

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

I haven been working with the Linux kernel for some time now and I am interested in adapting the Makefile structures used there. I want to achieve something similar by creating a set of Makefiles in each subdirectory which only consists the names of the files I really want to compile when building my project. A typical similar example achieved in the Linux kernel looks like this:

```
obj-y += file1.o
obj-y += file2.o
obj-y += file3.o
obj-y += file4.o
# ...
obj-d += somesubdir
```

Now, when building my project, I use the Makefile in my root directory to recursively include each Makefile in the individual subdirectories and append it to the list of the `obj-y` variable. My current approach is to define a recursive function which handles including the Makefiles and iterate through each subdirectory automatically:

```
OBJS :=

objtree  := .
srctree  := .

# ...

define build_subdir
objtree := $$(objtree)/$(1)
srctree := $$(srctree)/$(1)

obj-y :=
obj-d :=

include $$(srctree)/Makefile

OBJS += $$(patsubst %,$$(objtree)/%,$$(obj-y))

$$(foreach subdir,$$(obj-d),$$(eval $$(call build_subdir,$$(subdir))))

srctree := $$(patsubst %/$(1),%,$$(srctree))
objtree := $$(patsubst %/$(1),%,$$(objtree))
endef

# ...

$(eval $(call build_subdir,src))
$(eval $(call build_subdir,src/subdir))
```

While iterating through all subdirectories, I add the individual files to the `OBJS` variable which is then later used to compile the file.
However, the `OBJS` variable only contains the name of the object file (i.e. the target), not the name of the actual source file. This is problematic since the source files in my project do not consist only of `.c` but also some assembly files (`.S`). Therefore I am not able to define a recipe which looks like this:

```
define compile_file
$(1): $$(patsubst %.o,%.c,$(1))
        $(CC) $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)
endef
```

In my case, the compiler is always the same, so there's no problem in keeping the `$(CC)` variable as is. The same goes for the `$(CFLAGS)` variable.

Is there a way to achieve this similarily to the Linux kernel?

This is the current relevant content of my Makefile:

```
objtree  := .
srctree  := .

.PHONY: all
all: real-all

OBJS     :=

define build_subdir
objtree := $$(objtree)/$(1)
srctree := $$(srctree)/$(1)

obj-y :=
obj-d :=

include $$(srctree)/Makefile

OBJS += $$(patsubst %,$$(objtree)/%,$$(obj-y))

$$(foreach subdir,$$(obj-d),$$(eval $$(call build_subdir,$$(subdir))))

srctree := $$(patsubst %/$(1),%,$$(srctree))
objtree := $$(patsubst %/$(1),%,$$(objtree))
endef

# $(eval $(call build_subdir, src))
$(eval $(call build_subdir,src/arch/$(ARCH)))

define compile_file
$(1): $$(patsubst %.o,%.S,$(1))
    @echo "Compiling file $$< to file $$@"
endef

$(foreach file,$(OBJS),$(eval $(call compile_file,$(file))))

.PHONY: real-all
real-all: $(OBJS)
    @echo "real-all"
```

And the current output:

```
Compiling file src/arch/x86/a20.S to file src/arch/x86/a20.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/arch/x86/acpi.S', needed by 'src/arch/x86/acpi.o'.  Stop.
```

The last line obviously fails because there's no `src/arch/x86/acpi.S` file. Instead, the actual file is `src/arch/x86/acpi.c`. Thats what I addressed before with the issue being the source files can either be a `.c` or a `.S` file.

Comment: `a set of Makefiles [..] which only consists the names of the files I really want to compile when building my project`: what does this sentence mean exactly? What is the list `obj-y `? If you already know the name of the subfolders and their number is not too big you can write by hand.

Comment: `obj-y` is a variable which contains all object files. I simply add the object files from the "list" of `obj-y += ...` assignments in each Makefile. Also, the project is growing steadily. Another advantage of using this is that you are able to simply comment an assignment in order to exclude a file or even an entire subdirectory from the build process.

Comment: But why do you need a list of obj files in the root Makefile? It is better you give a [mcve].

Comment: I don't have a minimal example, the current approach is listed in my OP. As for why I need a list of object files: I can the use the `foreach` macro in order to compile each file individually by using a recipe (also listed in OP).

Comment: You should provide a minimal complete working example, if you don't have you should create it. For the output file you could create a Makefile for each subdir, iterate through all the subdirs and launch the corresponding Makefile that will create the output file.

Comment: I cannot post a working example since this is exactly what I'm asking about. I posted basically everything relevant ("*minimal*") from my Makefile. The only thing I cannot figure out is how to create a recipe when all I have is the name of the object file. I however need the name of the source file too in order to create a recipe in the form of `$(TARGET): $(SOURCE)`. And since the source file could either end with `.c` or `.S`, I cannot create a recipe and therefore I cannot provide a working example.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I edited my OP and include the part of the Makefile which gives me the current output I get when running it. The specific output is also included in the edited OP.

Comment: https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the `$(wildcard)` function in the following way:

```
define compile_file

srcbase := $$(basename $(1))
srcfile := $$(wildcard $$(srcbase).*)

$(1): $$(srcfile)
    @echo "[ CC ] $$@"
endef
```

Since `$(1)` contains the path to the file, `srcfile` matches the file by looking for the file with `$(wildcard $$(basename $(1)).*)`.

Now, I can compile all files easily.

Comment: Do you a have a complete working Makefile that can you post somewhere? I'm trying to do something similar. Thanks

Comment: @StackedUser you can check my current Makefile here: https://github.com/croemheld/elfboot/blob/master/Makefile